# How to include all files in a directory while using maven-replacer-plugin?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, maven-replacer-plugin

I want to replace token value in *all* the files inside a specific directory (say dir1):

Few examples:

1. /dir1/helloworld.jsp
2. /dir1/dir2/sample.jsp
3. /dir1/dir2/dir3/produtinfo.jsp
4. /dir1/random/dir3/dir4/random.jsp

I tried using following configuration which does not seem to be working

```
<configuration>
   <delimiters>
       <delimiter>@</delimiter>
   </delimiters>
   <basedir>target/dir1</basedir>
   <filesToInclude>*.jsp</filesToInclude>
   <tokenValueMap>/usr/home/output.properties</tokenValueMap>
</configuration>
```

Am I missing something here?

Also, I have two properties something like

prop1.value=10
prop2.prop1.value=20

so this plugin replaces "sample text ${prop2.prop1.value}" with "sample text prop2.10". How do I fix this?
It should update it with "sample text 20" instead.

In short, I want to replace some property values present in all the jsp files present inside src/main/webapp/jsp while building maven project so if there are any alternatives, please feel free to suggest.